# "Parsing error identifier expected" on v-on:change

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I had an issue where importing a class to be used only as a typescript type annotation caused a `no-unused vars` error. [This thread](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript/issues/5) said to add `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` to the eslint config, which solved the issue but caused more parsing errors:

- `ESLint: Parsing error: Identifier expected` which occurred on `v-on:change`
- `ESLint: Parsing error: '}' expected.` which occurred on `components: {}` in `@Component(...)`

`/App.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" style="height: 100%">
        <input v-on:change="onChange"/> <!--This is the "Identifier expected" error -->
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Foo from "@/path/to/Foo";
import Bar from "@/path/to/Bar";

@Component({
    components: {  //This is where the `'}' expected.` error occurs
        
    }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    onChange(e : any) : void {
        let f : Foo = Bar.baz();  //This is what caused the "no-unused-vars" problem before
        f.someFunc();
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is my Eslint config from package.json:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "@vue/typescript",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
}
```

I've tried enabling `vue/valid-v-on` in the `rules`, as well as each of the other `exports` used in the GitHub thread above.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've removed `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` from the eslint config, and put the line `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` above each "unused" import in the code. This is not an optimum solution, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (a year on): I've had this error a few times now, and I found that jsut restarting the TypeScript service usually fixes it.

At the bottom right of the IntelliJ Idea window, click on "Vue TypeScript ", then click "Restart TypeScript Service". After a second or two all the "errors" will have been reevaluated and anything incorrectly marked as an error should be cleared.

This can also be used to "fix" lots of other issues with the TypeScript error checker.

[image: The "Restart TypeScript" popup menu]

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same thing. I suspected that it's just a 'bad mood' of the computer... so I've put the line in comment and just wrote by myself the same thing underneath. The compiler stayed silent so I deleted the previous line.

Probably just a bug.

Comment: Which line did you delete?

Comment: The one that I put in comment

Comment: Probably there was something of a weird charachter between which not shown by the editor due to interpreted as a white space

Comment: True that. Or something similar

Answer (score 0):

skip @typescript-eslint/parser the vue file

add `.eslintignore` file

```
# @typescript-eslint/parser can not parse vue v-on
src/view/example/index.vue
```